# Is there a way to refresh JVM with new tgt when a new realm is added to the kdc?

Tags: hbase, kerberos, renewal, kdc

We have enabled security via Kerberos for all processes on a HBase cluster. When we add a new realm to the kdc we would like for all processes to see the new configuration without having to reboot or wait for the periodic tgt renewal.

Comment: What do you expect from this? Not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Add a new *realm*? Why? You mean you will dynamically create a new cluster, with its own Kerberos services, and specific user accounts w/ specific passwords???

Comment: Not dynamically create the cluster, services on it just need to be made dynamically accessible to services on a given cluster. The two clusters have different realms and the challenge is to add the cross-realm auth to a cluster and start communicating with it without having to wait for auto renewal of tgt as per earlier schedule. Is there a way to force tgt renewal when needed, without prior setup.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows we use for this purpose KerbTray (a tool from Window Server 2003 Resource Kit - 2003 but it still works, at least KerbTray). We right-click on its icon in system tray and from menu choose option "Purge tickets".

It's possible to do that in command line too, using Microsoft klist purge (as described here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh134826.aspx).